# apache-airflow: channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused

Tags: python, ubuntu, airflow

I am trying to build a data processing pipline. In a nutshell the pipline includes the follwing tasks: connect to a remote SQL db, extract data, process it and output files. I've built all these steps in python. Since the db is on a server I can only run the pipline only from a private server (with a static IP address) - for security reasons. So I ran all my py scripts from my own server (ubuntu). Now, to stitch the components of the pipilne I want to use apache-airflow. I followed a couple of instructions from different sources and failed to make it work. Everything seems to run but when I run airflow webserver the local host refuses the connection (for some reason). My question is rather general. I want to know if there is a good step by step instruction on how to install and use apache airflow specifically on remote server (ubuntu).

I have tried the following:

https://medium.com/@taufiq_ibrahim/apache-airflow-installation-on-ubuntu-ddc087482c14
https://vujade.co/install-apache-airflow-ubuntu-18-04/

https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-apache-airflow-df1aa77d7b1b

plus the same with docker.

[Here's the log of the error I get: (connection refused)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUiR4.png)

[Here's the the screen shot of when I run airflow webserver:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqmsP.png)

Comment: Can you provide logs/screenshots of refusing connection?

Comment: Hi. sorry for the vague post. I added the screen-shot. Thanks.

Comment: One more thing (didn`t understand from the post): you installed Airflow on the same machine as well as your DB, or on different?